# C++ double *() () { } overloading?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I have seen a Class like this:

```
class Vec2D {
    int i_;
    int j_;
    vector<double> vec;

public:
    Vec2D(int i, int j): i_(i),j_(j) {vec.assign(i_*j_,0);} 
    double & operator() (int i, int j){return ver[j_*i+j];} // overloading
    double * operator()(){return &(vec[0]); }               // ???
};
```

I understand `double & operator()` is for operator overloading.

As for `double * operator()(){return &(vec[0]); }`,  obviously it is used to return a pointer to the first element, but I don't understand the mechanism, is it an overloading or a function pointer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function call operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689430/function-call-operator)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it seems to me the link question is more concerned with "double operator()()" rather than double *operator()()

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but it is confusing, the linked answer suggested it is used as a functor, is it both operator overloading and functor ?

Comment: it's operator overloading that allows the object to be used as a functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator()` is the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

```
double * operator()(){return &(vec[0]); }
```

Defines a function call operator for `Vec2D` that returns a `double *` and takes no input.  You would use that in your code as

```
Vec2D foo;
double * bar = foo();
```

You then overload the function call operator with

```
double & operator() (int i, int j){return ver[j_*i+j];}
```

This defines a function call operator for `Vec2D` that returns a `double &` and takes in 2 `int`s.  It would be used like

```
Vec2D foo;
double & bar = foo(0, 0);
```

Comment: it seems to me both are about operator overloading, the only differences are 1- "double *()(){}" returns a pointer. 2- the second parenthsis takes no arguments. ?

Comment: @lorniper Yes these are overloaded functions.  One takes two parameters the other none.  Function overloading does not care about the return types.  The function parameters have to be different to overload a function.

Comment: Thanks ! So replace "double * operator()()" with "double * operator() (int i, int j)" would be illegal in this case ?