# Double brackets?

Tags: c++, c++11

Just encountered this bit of code:

```
if(iElement->getData().contains("someText") and iElement->getData()("someOtherText").toString() == "true")
```

What is boggling my mind is this part:

```
iElement->getData()("someOtherText").toString()
```

More precisely having: `()()`

I haven't seen an overloader anywhere.

This is supposed to be C++ code by the way.  Compiles and runs fine.

Could not find any information anywhere since I don't know what to even search for...  Can someone please explain?

Comment: I think the function call operator is being invoked on the object being returned by `iElement->getData()`, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689430/function-call-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MarekR as M.M has pointed out (comment now deleted), this is valid c++ code. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Brackets refers to the `[]` and they are not really involved in your question.

Comment: @super Nomenclature regarding brackets/braces/parentheses varies by region, so I wouldn't call this misleading. They did clarify that they mean `()`.

Comment: @super those are square brackets :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 iElement->getData()("someOtherText").toString()
```

Is processed in following order

1. Call `iElement->getData()`
2. On the object returned by `getData()`, call `operator()`, i.e the overloaded call operator, with the argument `"someOtherText"`
3. On the object returned by `operator()`, call `toString()`

Notice that `operator()` must not necessarily be overriden. `getData()` could e.g return a function pointer as well.

Comment: There's also a potential call of `operator->` on `iElement`, depending on what type it is.

Comment: *'On the result call `operator()` with argument "someOtherText", i.e the overloaded call operator'* seems to suggest you're invoking a user-defined operator, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

In question about `()()` first pair of parentheses corresponds to the call `iElement->getData()` returning callable object and second pair of parentheses represents `operator()` to call returned callable object with string parameter and returning type `String` (which has member function `toString()` as in source code for `String` in the source code below).
For our case we declare:

```
function<String (string)> callableObject;
```

This callable object is called as

```
callableObject(“callOperator or functionPointer or someOtherText”);
```

Callable object could be constructed using call operator or function pointer ([Sebastian Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60609662/7163942) and in the discussion) and other constructs (see source code for `getDataWithCallableObject()`):

```
         1 Function object
         1.1 Function object
               CallOperatorStruct callOperatorStruct;
               callableObject = callOperatorStruct;
         1.2 Lambda, named lambda
               String str;
               callableObject = [](string s) { return str; };
               auto namedLambda = [](string s) { return str; };
               callableObject = namedLambda;
         2 Function
         2.1 Free function
               callableObject = freeFunction;
         2.2 Free function pointer
               callableObject = &freeFunction;
         2.3 Member function
               callableObject = MemberFunctionStruct::staticMemberFunction;
         2.4 Member function pointer
               MemberFunctionStruct memberFunctionStruct;
               callableObject = bind (&MemberFunctionStruct::memberFunction, memberFunctionStruct, _1);
               callableObject = &MemberFunctionStruct::staticMemberFunction;
```

Source code

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct String {
  bool toString () {
    return "true";
  }
};

struct CallOperatorStruct {
  String operator()(string s) {
    return str;
  }

  String str;
};

struct Element {
  CallOperatorStruct& getData () {
    return data;
  }
  CallOperatorStruct data;

  static function<String (string)> getDataWithCallableObject ();
};

int main () {
  Element* iElement = new Element ();

  if (iElement->getData()("someOtherText").toString()){};

  if (iElement->getDataWithCallableObject()("someOtherText").toString()){};
}

String str;

struct MemberFunctionStruct {
  String memberFunction (string s) {
    return str;
  };

  static String staticMemberFunction(string s) {
    return str;
  };
};

String freeFunction (string s) {
  return str;
};

function<String (string)> Element::getDataWithCallableObject () {
  function<String (string)> callableObject;

  // 1 Function object
  // 1.1 Function object
  CallOperatorStruct callOperatorStruct;
  callableObject = callOperatorStruct;

  // 1.2 Lambda, named lambda
  callableObject = [](string s) { return str; };
  auto namedLambda = [](string s) { return str; };
  callableObject = namedLambda;

  // 2 Function
  // 2.1 Free function
  callableObject = freeFunction;

  // 2.2 Free function pointer
  callableObject = &freeFunction;

  // 2.3 Member function
  callableObject = MemberFunctionStruct::staticMemberFunction;

  // 2.4 Member function pointer
  MemberFunctionStruct memberFunctionObj;
  callableObject = bind (&MemberFunctionStruct::memberFunction, memberFunctionObj, _1);
  callableObject = &MemberFunctionStruct::staticMemberFunction;

  return callableObject;
}
```