# how to reassign value to an object using constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I came through a pretty interesting question... what can be the class declaration for the following segment of code in c++..

```
int main(){    
    Point f(3,4);        //class Point    
    f(4);    
}
```

the object declaration can be done by declaring a constructor f(int, int). But how can we use a constructor declaration to assign values to an object?? Even if define another constructor f(int), this will not work... as constructors are called only during object declaration. Please suggest a way to do this....

Answer (score 3):

You can use assignment operator:

```
Point f(3, 4);
f = Point(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(int,int);
    void operator()(int);
};
```

It is, of course, not a constructor in this case.  But that's how the syntax you showed could be legal.

Here's some more information about operator(): [Why override operator()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317450/why-override-operator)

Answer (score 0):

> > what can be the class declaration for the [above] segment of code in c++..

The obvious class declaration includes `operator()(int)`. A less obvious class declaration follows:

```
class Point {
typedef void (*FunPtr)(int);
public:
  Point(int, int) {}
  static void Fun(int) {}
  operator FunPtr() { return Fun; }
};
```

Comment: How will this do the required? Static functions can't access concrete object data.

Comment: @icepack: I don't believe that's a requirement.  I believe that the OP is just confused about some syntax he saw.  He mistakenly thought that it was calling a constructor, and that misunderstanding is what informed the odd wording in the rest of his question.

Comment: Right -- the first sentence of the question is the brain-teaser. The rest of it is OP's thinking about how to solve it.