# what is this para about on function objects

Tags: c++, stl

I came across this statement in a book and I don't understand it. The sentence is: "The templates in `<function>` help you construct objects that define operator(). These objects are called function objects and can be used in place of function pointers in many places".

Please tell me what `operator()` is, and I would also like some help in understanding what "*function object"* mean in this context.

Comment: [SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/functors.html) has in-depth explanations of function objects and all kinds of standard functors. I've found it to be a useful source of information back in the day. Note that a lot of the proposed solutions to programming problems in that documentation are deprecated in C++11, but it still answers your question.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Why override operator()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/317450/20984) [C++ functors and their uses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/20984)

Answer (score 2):

A *function object* (often called *functors*) is simply an object that can behave like a function. This is useful for example if you want a function that keeps track of something between calls.

To use an object like a function, you need to be able to call it, like this:

```
reallyAnObject(some, args);
```

You make this possible by overloading `operator()` for your class.

The [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header provides various useful tools to help you make function objects.

Here's a very simple example:

```
struct Functor {
    void operator() (int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Really an object. Called with " << i << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    Functor f;
    // prints "Really an object. Called with 1"
    f(1);
}
```

Now I suppose a more useful function might be to print a whole bunch of numbers, all to the same stream (still very contrived though):

```
struct Printer {
    std::ostream& os_;
    Printer (std::ostream& os) : os_(os) {}

    void operator() (int i)
    {
        os << i;
    }
};

int main() {
    // prints "12" to stdout
    Printer p {std::cout};
    p(1);
    p(2);

    // prints "34" to stderr
    Printer p2 {std::cerr};
    p2(3);
    p2(4);
}
```

More complicated examples are often useful to interact with the standard `<algorithm>`s.

The [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header provides lots of useful things that people often wrote themselves, for instance `std::plus`, `std::greater`, `std::unary_negate`. It also provides `std::function` and `std::bind`, but I'd stay away from those for now, they are a bit tricky.

Comment: can you please give me an example to expalin it further.

Comment: @codingisfun Was already writing it!

Comment: i think the output of above code will be Really an object.Called with 1 is it???

Comment: @codingisfun Correct.