# Can we use () instead of {} for function scope?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

What does this line means:

```
bool operator() (const song& s);
```

> I am not able to understand that line with operator.
>   Is operator some kind of keyword in c++?

Comment: need more context.

Comment: Yes, `operator` is a keyword in C++. It allows one to overload operators---in this case the "call" operator.

Comment: Please don't tag languages unrelated to the question (Fixed)

Comment: Yes, `operator` is a reserved keyword in C++.    The scope of the "line" is presumably within a `class` or `struct` definition, and is a declaration of a member function named `operator()` that accepts a parameter of type `const song &` and return a `bool`.   Given an instance of that `class` or `struct` named `x`, the expression `some_bool = x(some_song)` will call that function.   The function does need to be defined though.     In C, this question  is off-topic.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317450/why-override-operator
to understand use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use () instead of {} for function scope?

No, we cannot. `bool operator() (const song& s);` is a *function declaration*, not a definition. It declares a special function called `operator()`. `operator()` as a whole is the name of the function. The following `(const song& s)` is the list of function arguments. A definition of that function could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct song {
  char const* name;
};

struct A {
  void operator()(const song& s) {
    std::cout << "Received a song: " << s.name << '\n';
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;

  // Here's one way you call that function:
  a(song{"Song1"});

  // Here's another way
  a.operator()(song{"Song2"});
}
```

This is called operator overloading. You can learn more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: Thanks it worked and now I am able to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`operator` is a keyword used to define how your class will interact with the normal operators. It include things like +, -, *, >> ect.

You can find a full list at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

The way it's written is the keyword `operator` followed by the operator. So, `operator+`, `operator-` etc.

`operator()` refers to the function operator. If it's defined, then we can call the object like a function.

```
MyClass foo;
foo(); //foo is callable like a function. We are actually calling operator()
```

In your example, `operator()` is the function call operator and `(const song& s)` is the parameter passed to the function.