# Object(0,0) directly assigned value, how does that work?

Tags: c++

I got a homework which looks something like this. I am working on it and  hold beginner knowledge of the same.
I have to create a header file that contains this code and then use the header file to get the desired results.

I am working with C++ template, and operator overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "matrix.h"
#include "symetric_matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1; // Creates 3*2 matrix, with all the default elements set to 0;
    cout << m1 << endl;
    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m2(4); // Creates 3*3 matrix, with the default elements equals to 4;
    cout << m2 << endl;
    const Matrix<int, 3, 3> m3 = m2; // C-py constructor may take O(MN) and not O(1).
    cout << m3 << endl;

    // min() returns the minimal value in the matrix.
    if (min(m1) < min(m3))
        cout << "Min value of m3(" << min(m3) << ") is bigger than min value of m1(" << min(m1) << ")" << endl;

    if (m1.avg() < m3.avg()) // Compares the average of the elements
        cout << "Average value of m3(" << m3.avg() << ") is bigger than average value of m1(" << m1.avg() << ")" << endl;

    m2(0, 0) = 13;
    cout << m2[0][0] << " " << m2[1][0] << endl; // Should print "13 4"

    try
    {
        cout << m2 + m3 << endl;
        cout << m3 * m1 << endl; // You can choose the format of matrix printing;
        cout << m1 * m2;         // This should throw an exception
    }
    catch (const Matrix<int, 3, 2>::IllegalOperation &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m4;
    m4 = m3;
    cout << m4 << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            m4(i, j) = i + j;
    cout << m4 << endl;

    cout << "m4[1][1] = " << m4[1][1] << endl;

    cout << "m4[1][1] = " << m4(1, 1) << endl; // m4(1,1) same result as m4[1][1]

    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m5(3);
    m5 = 2 * m4;
    cout << m5 << endl;
    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m6(m4);
    cout << m6 << endl;
    m5 += m4;
    cout << m5 << endl;

    if (m6 != m5)
        cout << "m6 != m5" << endl;

    Matrix<Matrix<int, 3, 2>, 4, 4> composite(m1); // Creates matrix, where each element is m1;

    cout << composite;

    unique_ptr<Matrix<int, 3, 3>> symetric_matrix(new SymetricMatrix<int, 3>(5)); // SymetricMatrix matrix 3*3 with default element equals to 5;

    (*symetric_matrix)(1, 2) = 8;
    cout << (*symetric_matrix)(1, 2) << " " << (*symetric_matrix)(2, 1) << endl; // Should print "8 8"
    cout << (*symetric_matrix)[1][2] << " " << (*symetric_matrix)[2][1] << endl; // Should print "8 8"

    (*symetric_matrix)[1][0] = 18;
    cout << (*symetric_matrix)[1][0] << " " << (*symetric_matrix)[0][1] << endl; // Should print "18 18"

    return 0;
}
```

My **Updated** solution for now.

```
template <class T, int M, int N>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T mat[M][N];
    int rows = M;
    int cols = N;

public:
    // constructor
    Matrix(int v = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                mat[i][j] = v;
        }
    }

    Matrix<T, M, N> operator+(Matrix<T, M, N> &other);
    Matrix<T, M, M> operator*(T scalar);

    T &operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return mat[i][j];
    };

    T *operator[](int index)
    {
        return mat[index];
    };

    // << overloading
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix<T, M, N> &L)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                os << L.mat[i][j] << " ";
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    };

    friend T min(Matrix obj)
    {
        T result = obj.mat[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (result < obj.mat[i][j])
                    result = obj.mat[i][j];
        }
        return result;
    };

    long double avg() const
    {
        long double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (result < mat[i][j])
                    result = result + mat[i][j];
        }
        return result / (M * N);
    }
};

template <class T, int M, int N>
Matrix<T, M, N> Matrix<T, M, N>::operator+(Matrix &other)
{
    if ((this->rows == other.rows) && (this->cols == other.cols()))
    {
        Matrix<T, M, N> resultantMatrix;

        for (auto i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
            {
                auto &valueFirst = this->data[i][j];
                auto &valueSecond = other(i, j);

                if ((additionOverflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)) || (additionUnderflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)))
                    throw std::out_of_range("Resultant value of matrix is out of range");
                else
                    resultantMatrix(i, j) = valueFirst + valueSecond;
            }
        }
        return resultantMatrix;
    }
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");
}
```

I am confused about `m2(0,0) = 13` & `cout << m2+m3`, how does this work and how is this possible?
I just need help with the whole program while I try and learn!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to implement `operator()` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317450/why-override-operator), and `operator[][]` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload).

Comment: With `operator()` you can take the row and column as argument and return a reference to the value in the matrix and then assignment will alter the matrix. With `operator[]` you can only take one argument so you have to return a proxy object that remembers the matrix and row and has an `operator[]` taking the column argument and returning a reference to the value in the matrix. If your matrix is made up of vectors then the first `operator[]` can just return a reference to the vector.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow since this is a fixed-size 2D array, one can just return `mat[r]` from `operator[]`. No need for a custom proxy object. Not that I would recommend this.

Comment: I looked at both, I am trying to implement it but it is not working, can you tell me how it will be in my case? ```Matrix operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return mat[i][j];
    };``` This is my try.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that would be returning a reference to the vector.

Comment: `operator()` needs to return a `T&`, not a Matrix. And you should also have a const version of it.

Comment: @VanWilder Refer to [Template Matrix Class: implemented some basic functionalities](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237962/template-matrix-class-implemented-some-basic-functionalities).

Comment: How do I implement the `[]` one, the current one gives me an error. `invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript`

```T &operator[](int index)
    {
        return mat[index];
    };```

Help me with this too.

Comment: @VanWilder This is also given in the last shared [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237995).

Comment: Never put `using namespace std;` in a header file!!! Also don't forget the guard clauses.

Comment: Got it, Anoop Rana, I can't find the usecase there unless, I am missing something.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow according to my calculations that would be returning a pointer to a T.

Comment: `T &operator[](int index)` -> `T* operator[](int index)`.

Comment: @VanWilder You can search the keyword `[]` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237995) and you'll find it and use it as a reference.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. one more reason for a proxy object.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow There is no reason to have any kind of `operator[]`, but if you decide, [against reason](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array), to have one, you might just as well save some typing and use `T*` as your proxy object.

Comment: I would define `constexpr T& operator[](std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return mat[row][col]; }` with `-std=c++23` if I had to. The matrix should also have a row and column view to make `operator*` simpler.

Comment: How will I do the multiplication, I don't understand the example Anoop Rana linked me to. How do I incorporate into my example, if you can link me to a website where I can learn.

Comment: @VanWilder In the [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237962/template-matrix-class-implemented-some-basic-functionalities), there they have implemented the multiplication using `operator*`. Do you have doubts from that implementation? If yes, you can ask those doubts as separate questions explaining in detail which part you don't understand and which part you do understand.

Comment: ```error: no match for call to ‘(const Matrix<int, 3, 3>) (int&, int&)’
   84 |                 auto &valueSecond = other(i, j);
      |                                     ~~~~~^~~~~~
matrix.h:20:8: note: candidate: ‘T& Matrix<T, M, N>::operator()(int, int) [with T = int; int M = 3; int N = 3]’ (near match)
   20 |     T &operator()(int i, int j)
      |        ^~~~~~~~
matrix.h:20:8: note:   passing ‘const Matrix<int, 3, 3>*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers```  I am getting this while addition.